is xindy under use/development?
On one side, xindy seems to be the modern replacement of makeindex,
and in my distribution, there is a frequent update of the xindy version,
but it seems to be always 2.5.1-xxx.
Stackexchange has a tag xindy, so must be relevant.
The version on ctan, i.e. https://ctan.org/pkg/xindy is heavily outdated:
Versions 1.1 and 1.2 from year 2004 or that like.
There is a link to http://www.xindy.org but the versions there are as old as that.
And then there is https://github.com/jschrod/xindy.ctan, github of the author.
This is version 2.5.0 from year 2014.
Another point: packages relying on xindy. I found at least two of them.

glossaries (see manual section 1.3.2).
But maybe this is outdated as well replaced by glossaries-extra
splitindex but maybe this can use anything else
besides xindy and makeindex

So seemingly, from 2014 to now the version moved on from 2.5.0 to 2.5.1. Hm..
So my question: is xindy still relevant? Is it under development? Is it so mature that it does not change any more?
Where to find the most recent docs?

no, imho xindy has been abandoned. Use upmendex if you want a more modern variant of makeindex that can handle unicode.

@UlrikeFischer looks like an answer to me

Another index processor with the Unicode support is Xindex.

@UlrikeFischer I edited the question adding another aspect: other packages relying on xindy.

relevant to what or who? I use it routinely with glossaries (which is not obsolete - glossaries-extra is an extension of glossaries and not a replacement). (I've never heard of the alternatives others have mentioned here, even though they are part of tl.)

@cfr I must correct: can I say, that standalone use of glossaries is outdated, as it is loaded internally by glossaries-extra but... hm... maybe rarely by uptodate users (well I still use it so i am not an up to date user.. but i want to move)

@cfr I informed Nicola Talbot and asked for her opinion. Maybe she offers future support for xindex also or to upmendex..

who can say how widely used are upmendex and xindex?

The latex companion 2nd edition still mentions xindy.. well newer version I dont have.

@user2609605 xindy is in TLC3 but with clear limitations; xindex is also listed but again saying that it is not yet a full MakeIndex replacement. upmendex gets the most coverage after MakeIndex.

I'm wondering what an answer is beyond a summary of the comments already posted other than 'read TLC3'

@JosephWright I dont want to buy TLC3.

@JosephWright Interesting that you say: upmendex' covering is after that of makeindex still...

@user2609605 I basically use glossaries with xindy. is there a good alternative to glossaries?

xindy was recommended The LaTeX companion 2nd edition as it at the time looked quite promising. It supports many scripts and languages, but most of this support was developed prior to the widespread use of Unicode, and many aspects of it show that its original design assumes 8-bit codepages. The way it integrates into the TeX systems is in places a bit odd, at some time I had a hard time to get it working in a MikTeX system (imho the version change is from that time when the perl script was adapted to handle windows better, this was not done by the original author). The documentation is rather scarce and you don't find many help if you have questions.
As you found out development has stopped and I do not think that there will be future improvements or that someone will handle the deficits.
The LaTeX Companion 3rd edition therefore writes that you can continue to use it in existing projects if it works for you, but for new projects that need Unicode support we
recommend using upmendex or (with some caveats) xindex.

one last question: what are the caveats of xindex?

and a very last question: what about glossaries package which offers only alternatives makeindex and xindy.

@user2609605 you could buy the book and read what it says about xindex ... and regarding glossaries: ask the maintainer.

the first suggestion... hm... the second suggestion: I already wrote an email. Lets see.
